# $injector:modulerr Failed to instantiate module cloudinary due to $injecto <omitted>

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, bower, cloudinary

I am biulding a MEAN application. I started from this template: https://github.com/linnovate/mean

I want to add a module (called cloudinary) so I followed this: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#getting_started_guide
(ie: did a npm install and add the config in my server.js)

I also added this in my bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "cloudinary": "latest",
```

BTW, is this necessary? I did it to have access to cloudinary js file in my public/lib repo. Is this a good practice? 
I am not sure, but anyway it did create a public/lib/cloudinary rep.

Then I added this in my app.js:

```
angular.module('mean.mycars', ['cloudinary']);
```

I fllowed this for direct html upload: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_upload#direct_uploading_from_the_browser

So I added this to my assets.json file (wich add it to all my pages in the footer:

```
        "public/lib/cloudinary/js/jquery.min.js",
        "public/lib/cloudinary/js/jquery.ui.widget.js",
        "public/lib/cloudinary/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js",
        "public/lib/cloudinary/js/jquery.fileupload.js",
        "public/lib/cloudinary/js/jquery.cloudinary.js",
```

When I go to my app I get this js error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mean due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mean.mycars due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module cloudinary due to:
Error: [$injecto...<omitted>...1) angular.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.js:78
(anonymous function) angular.js:3745
forEach angular.js:323
loadModules angular.js:3711
createInjector angular.js:3651
doBootstrap angular.js:1379
bootstrap angular.js:1394
(anonymous function) init.js:8
trigger angular.js:2445
(anonymous function) angular.js:2716
forEach angular.js:330
eventHandler
```

I probably forgot to declare something somewhere, but don't know where too look...

Answer (score 0):

If find the solution. The problem wad that I declared 'cloudinary' as an angular module here:

```
angular.module('mean.mycars', ['cloudinary']);
```

But it seems that it's not an angular module. So I put this:

```
angular.module('mean.mycars', ['']);
```

and the error disapears.

Now I am not sure how to use cloudinary in my app, to upload an image via brower. It looks a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this response is several months removed from your original question, but maybe it can help someone else if you've already found a solution.

I am currently working through getting Cloudinary to work in my Angular.js application as well.  From what I can tell, you *will* need to inject 'cloudinary' as a module in your application in order for it to work.

There are **two** Cloudinary libs that you will need to include, and **load order is important**.  It looks like you're already including 'jquery.cloudinary.js'; you will also need to include 'angular.cloudinary.js' ([found here](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular)).  Make sure that 'jquery.cloudinary.js' is called **before** 'angular.js', and that 'angular.cloudinary.js' is called **after** 'angular.js'.  The cloudinary_angular project has a [helpful example on Github](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/blob/master/samples/photo_album).